# Javascript confirm redirect does not work properly

Tags: javascript, confirm

i´m trying to have a confirm box before users click on an external link,
Problem is my code redirect wether or not they click ok. It redirects on cancel also.
What is wrong?

The Link calls it with onclick="confirmLeave();"

```
    function confirmLeave() {
    if (confirm("Weiterleitung\n\n text text")) {
    window.open('https://...')
    } 
    else {
    console.log('stay here.');
                        return false
                    }}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (with proper indentation)

Comment: Remove "return false"

Comment: removing "return false" didnt change anything. But thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what goes wrong in your code, but here you have a working snippet.

```js
function leavePage() {
  if (confirm("You sure ?")) {
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
  } 
}
```

```html
<button onclick="leavePage()">Click</button>
```

Comment: My fault – i called the function after the "href" and now the behaviour makes total sanse to me. Thanks!

Comment: How is this an answer? Replacing an anchor (_"before users click on an external link"_) with a button completely changes the behavior.